# Batch file copying script giving errors on for loop

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I'm in the middle of writing a batch script that will copy a bunch of tiny files from one location to another, verify that the file exists in the new directory, delete the original, and move on. I've implemented a FOR loop to do this, but I can't seem to get it working. Any ideas?

```
::Copying files-
::For loop copies file, verifies file was copied,
::and removes file from source.
for %%f in (Q:%source%\*) do (
:recopy
copy %%f %dest%\%%f
if not exist %dest%\%%f goto recopy
set /a count+=1
del %source%\%%f
echo copied !count! of %total%
ping -n 1 -w 500 1.1.1.1 >nul
)
```

The inputs for the variables are as follows:

```
set /P source=Enter path to files on P:(Temp) drive (EX: jdoe\copy)

set dest=D:Temp\Copy
```

Scripted adding if network share is as follows:

```
net use Q: \\SERVER\Temp
```

The error given is:

> The system cannot find the file specified

and the error is repeated until the screen fills.

Full pastebin at http://pastebin.com/yjXP7H6U

Comment: this is not bash. please edit the title.

Comment: Damnit, I've been making that typo all day. I do both. :/ Thanks.

Comment: Try remarking out the `@echo off` at the top of the script and you can see what part of the script results in "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this before... Now I know whats wrong. The path is being copied on %%f

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a label within a for loop or if statement if memory serves.  You should move `:recopy` outside the loop.  Something like this:

```
::Copying files-
::For loop copies file, verifies file was copied,
::and removes file from source.
for %%I in (Q:\%source%\*) do (
    call :recopy "%%~fI" "%dest%\%%~nxI"
    set /a count+=1
    del "%%~fI"
    echo copied !count! of %total%
    ping -n 1 -w 500 1.1.1.1 >nul
)
goto :EOF

:recopy source dest
copy "%~1" "%~2"
if not exist "%~2" call :recopy "%~1" "%~2"
goto :EOF
```